# How to change required-indicator for rendered form from grails domain class

Tags: forms, grails

I am experiencing something strange. Having a domain [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbk6G.png) class with one property that is nullable:true and another that is nullable:false I expect to have the first one being render in generated view with * in the label * and the other without it. But both do not show it. I have other domain properties that have the indicator displayed.
Is this a bug or how do I change the behavior?

I do not use any plugin for this.

Many thanks
Sebastian

```
class Item {
    String req = "abc"
    String notreq
    int ammount = 1
    static constraints = {
      req nullable:false
      notreq nullable:true
    }
}
```

[image: screenshot of the form]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [default scaffolding template](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/651454b5a1ed0d8bf8be5e0c59980f7ae296b106/grails-resources/src/grails/templates/scaffolding/renderEditor.template#L267) it looks like String properties are only considered "required" if they are `blank:false` as well as `nullable:false`.

Comment: Thanks, I saw this some minutes ago... :)